# JavaScript : How to get an ID from newly generated tags by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would ask you for ideas of how to get a HTML's Tag ID from newly created buttons.
Though I successfully added a new column by a JS program to a Table, which was created by HTML, I could not do it to tables, which are **generated by a JavaScript program.**
So, I want you to help me to write JS codes to add a new column to newly JS-generated Tables.

Notes: now I can create a new Table by JS, but I could not add a new column to the table, mainly because I don't know how to get an ID from newly generated Tags.

Here are HTML and JavaScript codes:

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>
    ProjectManagementSystem
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="pms.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Manage Your Project</h1>
  <input type="button" class="AddPrj" value="Add a Project" onclick="addPrj('PMS')">
  <div id="PMS"></div>

  
  <input class="prjName" type="text" placeholder="Project Name">
  <table id="tbl" class="PMStbl" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="button" class="AddCln" value="Add a Column" onclick="insertColumn('tbl')">
      </th>
      <th>
        <input type="date">
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>PIC</td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Input Your Name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Task</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="dev">coding</option>
          <option value="rev">review</option>
          <option value="fix">fixed</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script src=pms.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript** (I try to write a function "insertColumn2" below)

```
//Function to add a new column to a JS-generated Table
const insertColumn2=()=>{
    //I want to carry out Functions below

}



//1-Function to add a new column to a Table, which is already created by HTML
const insertColumn=(tbl)=>{
    // Add a column to a Table
    let table = document.getElementById(tbl);
    let cell_1 = table.rows[0].insertCell(1);
    cell_1.innerHTML = '<input type="date">';
    let cell_2 = table.rows[1].insertCell(1);
    cell_2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="Input your Name">';
    let cell_3 = table.rows[2].insertCell(1);
    cell_3.innerHTML = '<select><option value="dev">coding</option><option value="rev">review</option><option value="fix">fixed</option></select>';
};




//2-Function to Create a new Table
const addPrj=(PMS)=>{
    //Get tag's IDs from the Table
    let $prjName = document.getElementsByClassName('prjName');
    let prjName =$prjName.length;
    let tableID = "tbl_"+String(prjName)
    let newPrjID = "prj_"+String(prjName)
    const newDiv = document.getElementById('PMS');
    //Create a new "Project Name" button
    let newPrj = document.createElement('input');
    newPrj.setAttribute("type", "text");
    newPrj.setAttribute("placeholder", "Project Name");
    newPrj.setAttribute("class", "prjName");
    newPrj.setAttribute("id",newPrjID);
    
   

    //Generate a new Table
    let table = document.createElement('table');
    table.setAttribute("border", "1")
    table.setAttribute("id",tableID);
    let thead = document.createElement('thead');
    let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

    table.appendChild(thead);
    table.appendChild(tbody);

    //Insert a new button and a new table
    newDiv.insertBefore(table, newDiv.firstChild);
    newDiv.insertBefore(newPrj, newDiv.firstChild);

    // Creating and adding data to first row of the table
    let row_1 = document.createElement('tr');
    let heading_1 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_1.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Add a Column" onclick="insertColumn2()">';
    let heading_2 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_2.innerHTML = '<input type="date">';


    row_1.appendChild(heading_1);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_2);
    thead.appendChild(row_1);


    // Create 2nd row data
    let row_2 = document.createElement('tr');
    let row_2_data_1 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_1.innerHTML = "PIC";
    let row_2_data_2 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="Input Your Name">';

    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_1);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_2);
    tbody.appendChild(row_2);


    // Create 3rd row data
    let row_3 = document.createElement('tr');
    let row_3_data_1 = document.createElement('td');
    row_3_data_1.innerHTML = "Task";
    let row_3_data_2 = document.createElement('td');
    row_3_data_2.innerHTML = 
    '<select><option value="dev">coding</option><option value="rev">review</option><option value="fix">fixed</option></select>';

    row_3.appendChild(row_3_data_1);
    row_3.appendChild(row_3_data_2);
    tbody.appendChild(row_3);
};
```

Thank you so much in advance for your kind support.

Comment: change this line in your create table function to send the argument for the new table's id, to your original addcolumn function. You can do this with template literal if you quote the assignment using back-ticks ``<input type="button" value="Add a Column" onclick="insertColumn(${tableID})">`` - the `tableID` variable will be replaced by the id value you assigned to it earlier in the function.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I would ask you more;  I added your advice "${table}", but this does not work. So, tell me which part to revise. Thanks in advance.  //2-Function to Create a new Table
`const addPrj=(PMS)=>{
    ...
    heading_1.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Add a Column" onclick="insertColumn(${tableID})">'; `

Comment: `${tableID}` - the name of the reference you made when adding the new table. For `${}` to be inserted as the value of the variable inside it, it must be inside back ticks, NOT`'` or `"`. Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals.

Comment: Thank you so much. The insertColumn still doesn't work. I posted the current codes as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't work with `id`. Instead of passing an `id` as argument to `insertColumn`, pass the table element itself. You can find out which table is the current one, by walking up the DOM tree from the `this` node:

```
onclick="insertColumn(this.closest(table))"
```

Repeat this in all your HTML tables.

Then in `insertColumn` adapt and remove the assignment to `table`, as `table` will now be the parameter name:

```
const insertColumn = (table) => { // Notice change of parameter name
    // Removed the assignment to table variable here
    let cell_1 = table.rows[0].insertCell(1);
    // ...etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To dear trincot, I would ask you more details as programs still did not work.

I changed the HTML and JS codes below, referring to your advice:
Thanks in advance so much for your supports.

HTML

```
<input type="button" class="AddCln" value="Add a Column" onclick="insertColumn(table)">
```

JavaScript

```
const insertColumn=(table)=>{
    // Add a column to a Table
    let tbl = document.getElementById(this.closest(table));
    let cell_1 = tbl.rows[0].insertCell(1);
    cell_1.innerHTML = '<input type="date">';
};
```

And

```
const addPrj=(PMS)=>{
    //Get tag's IDs from the Table
    let $prjName = document.getElementsByClassName('prjName');
    let prjName =$prjName.length;
    let tableID = "tbl_"+String(prjName);
    let newPrjID = "prj_"+String(prjName);
    const newDiv = document.getElementById('PMS');
    //Create a new "Project Name" button
    let newPrj = document.createElement('input');
    newPrj.setAttribute("type", "text");
    newPrj.setAttribute("placeholder", "Project Name");
    newPrj.setAttribute("class", "prjName");
    newPrj.setAttribute("id",newPrjID);
    
   

    //Generate a new Table
    let table = document.createElement('table');
    table.setAttribute("border", "1");
    table.setAttribute("id",tableID);
    let thead = document.createElement('thead');
    let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

    table.appendChild(thead);
    table.appendChild(tbody);

    //Insert a new button and a new table
    newDiv.insertBefore(table, newDiv.firstChild);
    newDiv.insertBefore(newPrj, newDiv.firstChild);

    // Creating and adding data to first row of the table
    let row_1 = document.createElement('tr');
    let heading_1 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_1.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Add a Column" onclick="insertColumn(this.closest(table))">'};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your kind supports, I would be almost there to complete my HTML and JavaScript codes. I would appreciate you if you could give me any information or advice.

Here are current HTML and JavaScript below. Now, the JS function `insertColumn()` does not work well. I would be very glad if you kindly could give me any solution?

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>
    ProjectManagementSystem
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="pms.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Manage Your Project</h1>
  <input type="button" class="AddPrj" value="Add a Project" onclick="addPrj('PMS')">
  <div id="PMS"></div>

  
  <input class="prjName" type="text" placeholder="Project Name">
  <table id="tbl" class="PMStbl" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="button" class="AddCln" value="Add a Column" onclick="insertColumn(`${tableID}`)">
      </th>
      <th>
        <input type="date">
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>PIC</td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Input Your Name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Task</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="dev">coding</option>
          <option value="rev">review</option>
          <option value="fix">fixed</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>







  <script src=pms.js></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript

```
//1-Function to add a new column to a Table, which is already created by HTML
const insertColumn=()=>{
    // Add a column to a Table
    let tbl = document.getElementById(`${tableID}`);
    let cell_1 = tbl.rows[0].insertCell(1);
    cell_1.innerHTML = '<input type="date">';
    let cell_2 = tbl.rows[1].insertCell(1);
    cell_2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="Input your Name">';
    let cell_3 = tbl.rows[2].insertCell(1);
    cell_3.innerHTML = 
    '<select><option value="dev">coding</option><option value="rev">review</option><option value="fix">fixed</option></select>';
};




    //2-Function to Create a new Table
    const addPrj=(PMS)=>{
        //Get tag's IDs from the Table
        let $prjName = document.getElementsByClassName('prjName');
        let prjName =$prjName.length;
        let tableID = "tbl_"+String(prjName);
        let newPrjID = "prj_"+String(prjName);
        const newDiv = document.getElementById('PMS');
        //Create a new "Project Name" button
        let newPrj = document.createElement('input');
        newPrj.setAttribute("type", "text");
        newPrj.setAttribute("placeholder", "Project Name");
        newPrj.setAttribute("class", "prjName");
        newPrj.setAttribute("id",newPrjID);
    
   

    //Generate a new Table
    let table = document.createElement('table');
    table.setAttribute("border", "1");
    table.setAttribute("id",tableID);
    let thead = document.createElement('thead');
    let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

    table.appendChild(thead);
    table.appendChild(tbody);

    //Insert a new button and a new table
    newDiv.insertBefore(table, newDiv.firstChild);
    newDiv.insertBefore(newPrj, newDiv.firstChild);

    // Creating and adding data to first row of the table
    let row_1 = document.createElement('tr');
    let heading_1 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_1.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Add a Column" onclick="insertColumn(`${tableID}`)">';
    let heading_2 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_2.innerHTML = '<input type="date">';


    row_1.appendChild(heading_1);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_2);
    thead.appendChild(row_1);


    // Create 2nd row data
    let row_2 = document.createElement('tr');
    let row_2_data_1 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_1.innerHTML = "PIC";
    let row_2_data_2 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="Input Your Name">';

    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_1);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_2);
    tbody.appendChild(row_2);


    // Create 3rd row data
    let row_3 = document.createElement('tr');
    let row_3_data_1 = document.createElement('td');
    row_3_data_1.innerHTML = "Task";
    let row_3_data_2 = document.createElement('td');
    row_3_data_2.innerHTML = 
    '<select><option value="dev">coding</option><option value="rev">review</option><option value="fix">fixed</option></select>';

    row_3.appendChild(row_3_data_1);
    row_3.appendChild(row_3_data_2);
    tbody.appendChild(row_3);

};
```

Comment: You haven't grasped how to use the template literals. The asignment that you have inside `'` quotes has to be inside back ticks. `<input type="button" value="Add a Column" onclick="insertColumn('${tableID}')">` - all of that in back ticks. `${tableID}` will be replaced with the value to assigned to it and will be inside single quotes. That is what you need. I think there are other problems and you may have to spend a little while understanding what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help.  I could manage to use what you mentioned, or the template literals. I would show each of codes as an answer thread.

Answer (score 0):

I could manage to write my codes of HTML and JS.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="ja">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>
    ProjectManagementSystem
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="pms.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Manage Your Project</h1>
  <input type="button" class="AddPrj" value="Add a Project" onclick="addPrj('PMS')">
  <div id="PMS"></div>

  
  <input class="prjName" type="text" placeholder="Project Name">
  <table id="tbl" class="PMStbl" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="button" class="AddCln" value="Add a Column" onclick="insertColumn(tableID)">
      </th>
      <th>
        <input type="date">
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>PIC</td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Input Your Name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Task</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="dev">coding</option>
          <option value="rev">review</option>
          <option value="fix">fixed</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script src=pms.js></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS

```
//1-Function to add a new column to a Table, which is already created by HTML
const insertColumn=(tableID)=>{
    // Add a column to a Table
    let tbl = document.getElementById(`${tableID}`);
    let cell_1 = tbl.rows[0].insertCell(1);
    cell_1.innerHTML = `<input type="date">`;
    let cell_2 = tbl.rows[1].insertCell(1);
    cell_2.innerHTML = `<input type="text" placeholder="Input your Name">`;
    let cell_3 = tbl.rows[2].insertCell(1);
    cell_3.innerHTML = 
    `<select><option value="dev">coding</option><option value="rev">review</option><option value="fix">fixed</option></select>`;
};

//2-Function to Create a new Table
const addPrj=(PMS)=>{
        //Get tag`s IDs from the Table
        let $prjName = document.getElementsByClassName(`prjName`);
        let prjName =$prjName.length;
        let tableID = "tbl_"+String(prjName);
        let newPrjID = "prj_"+String(prjName);
        const newDiv = document.getElementById(`PMS`);
        //Create a new "Project Name" button
        let newPrj = document.createElement(`input`);
        newPrj.setAttribute("type", "text");
        newPrj.setAttribute("placeholder", "Project Name");
        newPrj.setAttribute("class", "prjName");
        newPrj.setAttribute("id",newPrjID);
    
   

    //Generate a new Table
    let table = document.createElement(`table`);
    table.setAttribute("border", "1");
    table.setAttribute("id",tableID);
    let thead = document.createElement(`thead`);
    let tbody = document.createElement(`tbody`);

    table.appendChild(thead);
    table.appendChild(tbody);

    //Insert a new button and a new table
    newDiv.insertBefore(table, newDiv.firstChild);
    newDiv.insertBefore(newPrj, newDiv.firstChild);

    // Creating and adding data to first row of the table
    let row_1 = document.createElement(`tr`);
    let heading_1 = document.createElement(`th`);
    heading_1.innerHTML = `<input type="button" value="Add a Column" onclick="insertColumn('${tableID}')">`;
    let heading_2 = document.createElement(`th`);
    heading_2.innerHTML = `<input type="date">`;


    row_1.appendChild(heading_1);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_2);
    thead.appendChild(row_1);


    // Create 2nd row data
    let row_2 = document.createElement(`tr`);
    let row_2_data_1 = document.createElement(`td`);
    row_2_data_1.innerHTML = `PIC`;
    let row_2_data_2 = document.createElement(`td`);
    row_2_data_2.innerHTML = `<input type="text" placeholder="Input Your Name">`;

    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_1);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_2);
    tbody.appendChild(row_2);


    // Create 3rd row data
    let row_3 = document.createElement(`tr`);
    let row_3_data_1 = document.createElement(`td`);
    row_3_data_1.innerHTML = `Task`;
    let row_3_data_2 = document.createElement(`td`);
    row_3_data_2.innerHTML = 
    `<select><option value="dev">coding</option><option value="rev">review</option><option value="fix">fixed</option></select>`;

    row_3.appendChild(row_3_data_1);
    row_3.appendChild(row_3_data_2);
    tbody.appendChild(row_3);
};
```

Notes: HTML's button "Add a Column", which is initially shown in the browser, does not work instead of JS-generated buttons. I would appreciate it if you could kindly give me a comment as to this error (with the picture attached below)

[image]

Comment: p.s. Thank you so much for your supports and comments, dear all.